# How to remove Origin header in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I want to delete these two headers, but this is invalid
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

```
Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Origin");

Origin: https://localhost:44306
Referer: https://localhost:44306/
```

In Blazor Wasm

Comment: Fortunately, you **can't** remove / update these headers. If you could, it would have been a major security breach, because most security features of web sites rely on these headers. At least, because you live in the browser. Not from a backend host.

Comment: sad. Thank you. I want to realize the real-time collection of website information, but I find that such access is not feasible. Let me look at other similar projects

Comment: Razor no this, only in blazor(wasm, server not test)

Comment: You will have to run on server side to play this low level headers. A potential architecture, that won't cost a lot, is to delegate the web site analysing to a azure function. Microsoft offers a free plan that cover a certain amount of executions. This way, you may reach your goal, with a very small cost impact (depending on the actual usage of course)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll try it